# **kwargs not passing variables to function, what's wrong?

Tags: python

For some reason, I can't get the variables passed in **kwargs in Python to be seen by the receiving function.  (RESOLVED - see edit).  This illustrates the problem - the **kwargs parameters are passed through several functions and make it to the `integrand` function.  I put a print(kwargs) in there which displays the whole dictionary I created in the first few lines below.  BUT these variables aren't seen by the `integrand` function and it errors out.  What is the correct way to make these variables accessable to the final function?  Much appreciated, searched quite a few posts on SO but couldn't find something directly relevant to my case.

```
def integrand(x, F, K, T1, T2, vol, flag):
    print(kwargs)
    d1 = (np.log(x / (x+K)) + 0.5 * (vol**2) * (T2-T1)) / (vol * np.sqrt(T2 - T1))
    d2 = d1 - vol*np.sqrt(T2 - T1)
    mu = np.log(F) - 0.5 *vol**2 * T1
    sigma = vol * np.sqrt(T1)
    value = lognorm.pdf(x, scale=np.exp(mu), s=sigma) * (flag * x*norm.cdf(flag * d1) - flag * (x+K)*norm.cdf(flag * d2))
    return value

def integrate(x, w, a, **kwargs): 
    return np.sum(w*transform_integral_negative1_1_to_0_1(x, a, **kwargs))

def transform_integral_0_1_to_Infinity(x, a, **kwargs): 
    return integrand(a+(x/(1-x)), **kwargs) *(1/(1-x)**2); 

def transform_integral_negative1_1_to_0_1(x, a, **kwargs): 
    return 0.5 * transform_integral_0_1_to_Infinity((x+1)/2, a, **kwargs)

flag = current_opt[i,0]
F = current_opt[i,1]
K = current_opt[i,2]   
T2 = current_opt[i,3]
T1 = current_opt[i,4]
r = current_opt[i,5]
vol = current_opt[i,6]

a = 0
b = np.Inf
kwargs = {'flag':flag, 'F':F, 'K':K, 'vol':vol, 'T2':T2, 'T1':T1}
integrate(x, w, a, **kwargs)
```

And this is what is printed before it errors out `print(kwargs)`:

```
{'F': 1.2075, 'flag': -1.0, 'K': 0.12509999999999999, 'T2': 0.068500000000000005, 'vol': 0.42999999999999999, 'T1': 0.041099999999999998}
```

And the error, despite K being defined above:

```
NameError: name 'K' is not defined
```

The solution was to define each input rather than extract each value from the dictionary...  The `**kwargs` passed to the last function extracts all the keyword arguments automatically.

Comment: mgilson's answer is perfect, I have closed this as a dupe of a similar post with more details.

Comment: Try adding `K = kwargs['K']`, etc.

Comment: as a side note if you want to take specific arguments like `K` then take those specific arguments: `def integrand(x, F, K, T1, T2, vol, flag):...` you can still pass them as keywords but don't have to worry about `**` mechanics. (also can specify defaults for some / all of them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`**kwargs` is passed as a `dict` to the function, it doesn't automatically populate the function's locals.

e.g.:

```
kwargs = {'K': 1}

def foo(**kwargs):
    print(K)

def bar(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['K'])

foo(**kwargs)  # NameError
bar(**kwargs)  # Works Ok.
```

Comment: The easier way to do this is to define each variable in the `integrand` function above instead of accepting `**kwargs` as an input, then pass `**kwargs` to that function and it will unpack the keywords, eliminating the need to extract each value from the dictionary 1 by 1.  That is the answer I was looking for!!!!

Comment: @Matt -- Yes, definitely easier that way.  :)